# Hard drive configuration advice

Tags: hard-drive, raid, redundancy

I've got a few hard discs that I'd like to put in some sort of redundant configuration.  Their sizes are:

- 600 GB
- 1 TB
- 2 TB

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'd like to be able to abstract the whole setup to look like a single drive in Windows (but with redundancy so I can recover data if a hard drive fails).

How would people recommend I use these hard drives?  Is there a RAID configuration that would allow me to do what I want?  How much available space would I have after the space used for redundancy is taken into account?

**Note:** I have an Intel G33 Express chipset with ICH9R, which supports Raid 0, 1, 5, and 10.  I'll be running Windows 7 as my primary OS (Windows 7 will be installed on a separate disc - a small SSD)

Comment: What hardware and software is available to you?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, edited to elaborate on your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you meant 600GB, not 600MB. If you still have a 600MB HD time to recycle it.

Most OSes will allow you to create a 1TB and 0.6TB partition on the 2TB drive, then mirror those partitions to the two other drives. This will only give you 1.6TB of usable redundant space, and another 0.4TB of non-redundant space. It's less than ideal, but will afford you some level of redundancy.

Comment: Install Windows; open Disk Management, convert the drives to Dynamic if necessary. Create mirrored partitions (start each mirror by selecting the smaller 1TB and 600GB disks and place the mirror on the larger disk). Optional: create a 400GB non-redundant partition. You can also mount these as subfolders of another drive so you don't end up with C: D: E:... unless you want those.

Answer (score 0):

if you use 2 tb and 1 tb in raid 1. then you can able to use only 1 tb for usage.

if u want use for backup the data go for raid 1.

you cannot make use 600mb in raid. if u try to configure raid 5 with 3 disk it will take 600mb from each and able store 1.2 gb space.
you cannot create raid 1 with 3 .

you can try raid 1e

Comment: OSes can apply RAID to partitions in addition to disks. What you describe is limited to conventional HBAs. It would help if you explained what RAID1E is too...